# How to hexdump few lines in a large using only line number.(Not bytes)

Tags: packet-capture, hexdump

I am using hexdump to display file in a readable format. The file is quite large and i know only the line numbers. length of lines are uncertain (may be 10 characters or 100 characters).

Is there any option to hexdum few line suppose 5 to 10 or 17-25.
I have read the man page and a better explanation from [here](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/making-sense-hexdump/).
But I couldn't get my answer.

So please help me.

Thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged the article with "wireshark", "packet-capture", and "packet-sniffers", but if the file in question is a capture file from Wireshark (or from tcpdump), it doesn't have lines terminated by LF or CR/LF, it has records that have length fields near the beginning, and if you want to display it in a readable format, use TShark or tcpdump to read it and print out the packets.

Comment: ok.
my mistake.
actually I have a file on my local host and i can see that in vi but I am seeing "." in place of unprintable characters.
I just want the real hex value of those characters.

Comment: Is it a text file, so that the "unprintable" characters are still text (for example, UTF-8 text), or is it a *binary* file, so that it doesn't necessarily have lines, but in which *some* of the binary data happens to be text?  What program produced the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to cut the right lines from a file and pipe them into hexdump? For example,

`cat myfile | sed -n '17,25 {p;n;n;}' | od -x`

might be close to what you need if you want to dump lines 17 to 25 of `myfile`